# shutdownNow with executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for a connection task as below:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<ApplicationConnection> future = (Future<ApplicationConnection>) executor.submit(new ConnectThread(crf, connoptions));
connection = future.get(300000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.shutdownNow();
```

The `call()` method calls a `.connect()` method (proprietary API).  This connect method spawns various threadpools etc.  My concern is that if the future times out and kills the executor, will the threads that may have already spawned by calling the `.connect()` method in the future also end?  I know that killing a thread will also kill any child threads but does this follow the same logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your assumption, if the `Future` times out, some hanging threads will remain. Even worse, `shutdownNow()` will not even shutdown your pool thread (not to mention proprietary API threads). It merely stops accepting new jobs. `ExecutorService` thread pool will terminate all threads once all running tasks finish.

What you can do is to try canceling the future and interrupting it. First handle `InterruptedException` inside your future:

```
class ConnectThread implements Callbale<ApplicationConnection> {

    public ApplicationConnection call() {
        try {
            return prioprietaryApi.connect();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            prioprietaryApi.cleanUp();
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

Now simply run:

```
future.cancel(true);
```

However your proprietary API might not handle `InterruptedException` (it will not rethrow it from `connect()`, moreover you might not have access to any `cleanUp()` method.

In these circumstances just... forget about it. That `Future` will eventually terminate and clean up after itself, ignoring the fact that you no longer wait for it. Of course this might lead to various scalability issues.

BTW if the only thing you want to achieve is limiting the maximum time given method runs, consider [`TimeLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) from [guava](/questions/tagged/guava).

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, what I'm doing now WILL leave hanging threads but eventually the Future will terminate and clean up after itself?  The inclusion of future.cancel(true) would only be beneficial if the connect() method can handle an InterruptedException?

Comment: @Greg: the fact that you no longer wait for the `Future` doesn't mean that it not running anymore. And when it finishes it will clean up just as usual, however no one is really waiting for the results.

Answer (score 1):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of
>   waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution. There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop
>   processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical
>   implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that
>   fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Comment: so in saying that, you are saying that any spawned threads should also end when the service is shutdown with shutdownNow?  If I were to use shutdown, then everything would finish (including spawned) before the Executor Service was shut down?

Comment: No, shutdownNow() doesn't guarantee that, shutdown() guarantees that behavior.